# Maui "Count Button" project results in "Error APT2000 cannot find the file specified" on Android emulator

Tags: c#, .net, android-emulator, maui

I just got myself into .NET MAUI using Visual Studio on Windows.
I'm using the "Count Button" basic program but while I successfully made it run on Windows, I couldn't made it run on Android, even using different android emulators (with different APIs versions).

This is what my Console sent back :

```
`L'opération de génération a démarré...
Démarrage de l'émulateur nexus_5_-_api_33...
1>------ Début de la génération : Projet : Phoneword, Configuration : Debug Any CPU ------
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -netfast -accel on -avd nexus_5_-_api_33 -prop monodroid.avdname=nexus_5_-_api_33
1>Les analyseurs ont été ignorés pour accélérer la génération. Vous pouvez exécuter la commande « Build » ou « Rebuild » pour exécuter des analyseurs.
1>Phoneword -> C:\Users\Marou\Documents\Développement mobile\cours\Phoneword\Phoneword\bin\Debug\net6.0-android\Phoneword.dll
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\32.0.476\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets(212,3): error APT2000: Le fichier spécifié est introuvable. (2).
1>Génération du projet "Phoneword.csproj" terminée -- ÉCHEC.
========== Build : 0 réussite(s), 1 échec(s), 0 à jour, 0 ignorée(s) ==========
========== 00:15,658 écoulé ==========
========== Déploiement : 0 réussi, 0 a échoué, 0 ignoré =========
========== 00:15,659 écoulé ==========
L'émulateur nexus_5_-_api_33 est en cours d'exécution.`
```

Thank you for any help or advice.

I tried to run the basic Count Button Program for MAUI projects on Visual Studio.
I expected for the Android emulation to work the same way as the Windows tryout, but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build error is caused by putting project in a folder/directory containing some `non-ASCII` chars, like Czech alphabet (tested with `á`) breaks Android build.
However, this does not affect any other C# projects.

For more details, you can refer to [Android - APT2000 build error when project path contains non-ASCII symbols](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6925) and [Application cannot be deployed on Android (APT error APT2000)](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5642).

Comment: Thank you so much, it was indeed the issue.
I'll now begin my journey.
Thank you again.