# Error "cannot find the file specified" on Android emulator" when debugging on the device android

Tags: c#, android, maui

When I want to debug my newly created .Net MAUI application on my real android device I get this error  "APT2000 cannot find the file specified(2)"

The error occurs when trying to launch absolutely any project

Comment: I know you say any project, but does it happen when you run the sample project(s)? https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples.  More information from the error log would be helpful, as APT2000 could be literally anything.

Comment: Is the project in a folder/directory containing any non-ASCII chars? like Czech alphabet?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could refer to this thread: [Maui "Count Button" project results in "Error APT2000 cannot find the file specified" on Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74591711/maui-count-button-project-results-in-error-apt2000-cannot-find-the-file-speci)